# jQuery fadeOut() on Divs with Background Color in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-effects

I have a Javascript function that fades out a standard div with a background color using jQuery fadeOut(). It works fine in Chrome & Firefox but when I try it in IE, the text fades out but the background color remains the same and just disappears without fading out once the text fade has finished. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks,

DLiKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the clearType filter that IE applies:

```
$('#fadingElement').fadeIn(2000, function(){
    $(this).css('filter','');
});
```